# Users can restore removed inapp purchases?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my app I would like to replace an in-app purchase by a new one.

Users can restore the previous in-app purchase if the in-app is deleted or just hidden?

Thanks.

EDIT: I mean restored an in-app removed from iTunes connect.

Are the in-app are stored in the itunes servers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if is already bought it; the same thing with app: the user can restore the app even if you remove the app from sales after he already bought it.

The restore functions restores all transactions from your app that was ever made from your Apple!

But, you can check in

```
paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished
```

all the restored `productIdentifier` and "respond" accordingly